# Loading spinner for Xamarin Forms without User Controls

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, spinner, loading

I am currently searching for a fast loading spinner / Activity indicator in Xamarin Forms without adding user control to XAML. We would need support for Android, UWP and iOS.

Any other ideas? All ideas would be appreciated. Thank you a lot.

Acr.UserDialogs currently slows up our dialogs and our navigation becomes very slowly so we would like to replace it.
I tried to implement AiForms.Dialogs, but there is no support for UWP.

Comment: Create a custom control : https://github.com/almirvuk/UWPCustomControlExample?force_isolation=true

Comment: Recommendations for tools and controls are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately the code has to be ViewModel - only. In a current state we can not use user controls which has to be bound into xaml

Comment: If you're following the MVVM pattern (why else would you have a ViewModel?), your ViewModel shouldn't know about Views or anything directly View-related. Please elaborate on the reasons and the problem in your question and rephrase it accordingly. There may be another way to solve this without breaking MVVM. Currently, it seems off-topic.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the code behind file? If so could you not use it to add an `Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator` to the View and bind it to an `IsBusy` property in the ViewModel?

Comment: *"Unfortunately the code has to be ViewModel - only. In a current state we can not use user controls which has to be bound into xaml"* - this statement is nonsensical. By definition, a viewmodel does not contain UI code. Your View is going to refer to a custom control, whether you write it yourself or use a third-party one..

Comment: Try with [AiForms.Dialogs](https://github.com/muak/AiForms.Dialogs)